# Passing a range table to an ABAP class/method causes a commit

Tags: methods, parameters, range, abap

[image: Short Dump from RSA3]

I want to pass a range table for OBJNR, e.g.

```
    call method ME->ME_GET_STATUS
      exporting
        I_OBJNR                  = <FS_DATA>-OBJNR_NTF
        I_AEDAT                  = LV_AEDAT
        I_AEZEIT                 = LV_AEZEIT
        IT_OBJNR                 = LR_OBJNR
      importing ...
```

In the PUBLIC section of the super class I have:

```
    RT_OBJNR                  type range of JSTO-OBJNR . (this is inherited by the calling class)
```

which is used by both calling & called methods.

The method ME_GET_STATUS has a parameter:

> IT_OBJNR    Importing   Type    RT_OBJNR     Range table for OBJNR

and code

```
     ,WA_OBJNR                   like line of IT_OBJNR
     ,LR_OBJNR                   type RT_OBJNR

  LR_OBJNR[] = IT_OBJNR[].
```

The range table is only used to buffer an itab - LT_JCDS.

```
select S~OBJNR, S~STAT,  S~CHGNR, S~UDATE, S~UTIME,
         S~INACT, O~OBTYP, O~STSMA
    from JCDS  as S
    join JSTO  as O
      on O~OBJNR = S~OBJNR
    into table @IT_JCDS
   where S~OBJNR in @LR_OBJNR
   order by S~OBJNR, S~UDATE, S~UTIME, S~STAT, S~CHGNR
         
loop at IT_JCDS into data(LT_JCDS)  
               where OBJNR = I_OBJNR
    
  group by ( OBJNR = LT_JCDS-OBJNR  STAT = LT_JCDS-STAT
             GS  = group size GI = group index     )
        ascending
        reference into data(OBJNR_REF)
```

It all works perfectly if there is just 1 record in the range table.

The issue is that if I pass more than 1 record it still works fine but seems to cause a commit (?) which closes the cursor causing a dump in `MCEX_BW_LO_API`. This occurs when calling the macro "sel" for the 2nd data package.

The idea is to pass multiple records of 'EQ' and 'BT' selections resulting in fewer records being returned from the database.

I've tried changing to a standard table and using `= LR_OBJNR[]`

Comment: We're passing range tables a lot and never observed something like unexpected commits. A range table is basically just a standard table with a normalized format. It has no connection to the database. My impression is that there is something else at work here, such as other statements or function calls that cross system or transaction borders. Your snippets are too short to tell, though. You're saying you tried changing to a standard table - did this improve things? If you're still seeing those commits then, they're likely not related to the range table.

Comment: I know it sounds strange but it works 100% with just 1 record in the range table. When there are two or more the method appears to work fine but then it fails when preparing the next data package.

Comment: Do a SQL trace (`ST05`) to find out what ABAP code triggers the COMMIT. Note specific to your program: [2854781 - Runtime Error DBSQL_INVALID_CURSOR occurs when testing datasource with RSA3](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002854781)

Comment: Thanks, ironically there was a `WAIT` statement used for debugging.
kudos to @SandraRossi